# MouseClick event doesn't invoke on click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseclick-event

I'm having a problem while assigning a function to the MouseClick event while outside of my form class.

When i click my mouse button the event doesn't invoke.

```
class Animator
{  
    Form1 _form = new Form1();
    Timer GameTimer;
    PictureBox GameWindow;

    public Animator(Timer gameTimer, PictureBox gameWindow)
    {
        GameTimer.Tick += GameTimer_Tick;
        GameTimer.Start();
        _form.MouseClick += Mouse_Clicked;            
        GameWindow.Paint += GameWindow_Paint;
    }

    private void Mouse_Clicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("I AM CLICKED");           
    }
```

Comment: Your form isn't showing.  At least, not the one in this code.

Comment: The example you're showing does not reproduce the problem. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting your question.

Comment: @RufusL Form1 is already showing.  The OP is assigning the MouseClick to the wrong form.

Comment: @RufusL I'm pretty confident the evidence is all there.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah, I think you're right. I deleted my comments. :)

Answer (score 2):

If this method is being called from an existing form, then you probably just need a way for the form instance to be passed to the method (currently you're interacting with a *new* form). One way to do this would be to add a `Form1` parameter to your method:

```
class Animator
{
    private Form1 _form;

    public Animator(Form1 form)
    {
        _form = form;
        _form.MouseClick += Mouse_Clicked;

        // rest of code ommitted...
```

Then, when you instantiate `Animator` from `Form1`, you would pass in an instance of the form:

```
Animator animator = new Animator(this);
```

---

If you're actually intending on creating a new instance of `Form1`, then you need to call `_form.Show` so you can interact with the form:

```
class Animator
{
    private Form1 _form = new Form1();

    public Animator()
    {
        _form.MouseClick += Mouse_Clicked;
        _form.Show();

        // rest of code ommitted...
```